# MacBook Pro going to sleep by itself because of watchdog daemon

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos, sleep-wake

For a couple of weeks, my Mac has been going to sleep by itself. This seems to happen more often when I'm running more stuff on my Mac (Chrome + Spotify + etc…)

In my console, the message is the following:

```
1/4/15 7:24:04.793 PM coreaudiod[293]: 2015-01-04 07:24:04.792840 PM [AirPlay] Power: SystemWillSleep
```

Followed by:

```
1/4/15 7:24:04.794 PM coreaudiod[293]: 2015-01-04 07:24:04.794130 PM [AirPlay] BTLE client stopping to browse for AirPlay Solo Target Presence.
1/4/15 7:24:04.795 PM coreaudiod[293]: 2015-01-04 07:24:04.795289 PM [AirPlay] BTLE discovery removing all devices
```

This seems to have some sort of correlation with `watchdog`, a daemon process on my mac (In this case it's happening after, but it's usually before).

```
1/4/15 7:24:04.800 PM watchdogd[7673]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000280 msg=0x570033
1/4/15 7:24:04.800 PM watchdogd[7673]: [watchdog_daemon] @(    wd_daemon_thread) - events buffer: 6329r81941 6779s81941 
1/4/15 7:24:04.838 PM watchdogd[7673]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000320 msg=0x0
1/4/15 7:24:04.838 PM watchdogd[7673]: [watchdog_daemon] @(         pm_callback) - ref=0x0 msg_type=0xe0000300 msg=0x0
```

Here are some more logs:

The `SystemWillSleep` messages:

[image]

Watchdog Processes:

[image]

Full Log for 7:12 PM:

[image]

Some system information: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13 inch, Late 2013) running Yosemite.

Comment: I didn't setup watchdog myself. I'm not sure what started it (or what it's for exactly). I've tried killing it `kill -9 PID_OF_WATCHDOG` and it just restarts itself.

Comment: Is your smartphone or anything with magnetics touching your Macbook when it sleeps by itself?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the readout from your logs.

Your BTLE (Bluetooth low energy) is shutting down (normal ?)

The `watchdogd` is shutting down the corresponding processes, but is is not meant to shut down your system.

The `SystemWillSleep` is for the `coreaudiod`, due to the airplay shutting down, it does not mean the OS X shutting down.

All of the above is happening because the OS X received the sleep command (they happen after the command was issued).

The OS X will sleep if you have something like `kernel[0]: sleep`

and more info can be found

```
kernel[0]: Previous Sleep Cause: 5
```

New logs show:

Your system did enter the sleep mode.

It was woken up by the RTC Alarm. Check your Energy Saver settings-

It was woken up by the WOMP since it is enabled ([Wake On Magic Packet](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201960)) a network.

To see all wake up reasons use `syslog |grep -i "Wake reason"` in your Terminal.

So far your system is not acting strange, just doing what you asked it to do. The "restarts" you are referring to are the wakes ups from sleep mode. There is no log entry showing that the system has restarted.

If it did the restart then you would see for example:

```
shutdown[15811]: SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1424885403 656386

bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1424885410 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. In fact I disabled watchdogd using launchctl and there where no more log entries related to it, but the issue happened again.

Comment: Beside, my problem is with the system restarting, not sleeping. :( Here is a screenshot of the logs around the time when the system tries to shut down: http://cl.ly/image/0G1Z1817010O as you can see, there is a 1-hour with no entries (here is another one from this morning http://cl.ly/image/2O2l3F0V3p2f). It looks like that the system got to sleep, but it is configured not to, and when I come back to the machine, I always discover that it actually tried to shut down (and some open application prevented it).

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. We have a couple of issues here: 1. My system should NOT got to sleep. 2. You're right that it doesn't restart, but that's just because I have an open application or such stopping it. By the time it gets there, it has already closed 5-10 other apps though... pretty annoying.

Edit: the sleep thing is ok, I fixed it.

Comment: what did you fix ?

Comment: I am still confused with your sleep settings. Please run the "pmset -g assertions" in terminal and report the result.

Comment: (just awarded you the bounty... at lest you get the full amount) my sleep settings are: https://gist.github.com/GaretJax/f92349df402730ec8ded

Answer (score 1):

I found [Mac OS X Server: About the Watchdog Process](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20622). Are you running any server software on it? (file servers?)

> #### Automatic Restart (hardware)
>
> Watchdog also helps restart the server if its operating system becomes unresponsive (a "hang"). On computers that support automatic restart, this option can be activated in the Energy Saver pane of System Preferences. Once activated, Watchdog periodically resets the computer's Power Management Unit (PMU) timer. If this timer expires (which happens if the system hangs), the PMU forces a restart.

Is your system "Hanging"? Is a piece of software causing it or being recognized as one?

Comment: It only happens when I'm away from the computer for a while. So no way to tell if it hangs. I also searched the whole disk for a `watchdog.conf` file and didn't found anything.

Comment: And no, no file servers.